# MS Access converting .csv to .xls

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, csv, xls

Here is my code, but for some reason it is failing on the saveas line (object does not support, etc).

```
Sub convertToXLS()
    Dim wb As Object
    Set wb = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim strFile As String
    strFile = "C:\path to my file\filename.csv"

    wb.Workbooks.Open (strFile)
    With wb
        .SaveAs FileName:=Replace(strFile, ".csv", ".xls")
        .Close True
    End With
    Set wb = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `wb` is `Excel.Application` object, rather than `Excel.Workbook`. And `Excel.Application` doesn't support `SaveAs` method. User this one instead:

```
Sub convertToXLS()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim wb As Object
    Dim strFile As String

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")        
    strFile = "C:\path to my file\filename.csv"    
    Set wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile)

    With wb
        ' where 56 is value of excel constant xlExcel8
        .SaveAs FileName:=Replace(strFile, ".csv", ".xls"), FileFormat:=56 
        .Close True
    End With
    'clean up
    Set wb = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: It worked but when I try to open the .xls, it says it's in a different format than the file extension

Comment: yeah, you should check my updated answer, use `.SaveAs FileName:=Replace(strFile, ".csv", ".xls"), FileFormat:=56`

Comment: Nevermind, missed the edit. That fileformat thing resolved the issue. What is fileformat 56? .xls format?

Comment: yes, `FileFormat:=56` the same as `FileFormat:=xlExcel8` (`.xls`), however since you're using this macro from Access, Access doesn't know anything about excel constants untill you add reference to Excel library. That's why I'm using constant value `56` instead constant itself